# Finite duration vs infinite duration sequences?

Tags: discrete-signals

What are difference between finite duration and infinite duration sequences?
As far as i am able to google and know only one difference that is finite duration sequence ROC exist on
xy plane while infinite duration sequence ROC exist on unit circle plane

I have also attached two snapshots in this regard 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight misunderstanding here. There is no such plane called unit circle plane. Unit circle is in the xy plane (or we call it z plane). The difference is, rather, in the shape of the ROC. For infinite duration sequences, the ROC is in the form of a circular strip in the xy plane (as shown in the second figure).

In the case of finite duration sequences, ROC is the entire xy plane except at z=0 or at z = $\infty $ or at z=0 and $\infty$.

e.g. $x(n) = \{1,\underset{\uparrow}{2},3\} $

$X(z) = \sum \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(n)z^{-n}$

$ = x(-1)z^1+x(0)z^0+x(1)z^{-1} = z+2+\frac{3}{z}$

This Z transform will not exist only if $z=\infty$ (for the first term) and $z=0$ (for the last term). This can be generalised for all finite duration signals that their ROC consists of entire z plane (xy plane) except at z=0 or z=$\infty$ or at both.

Comment: Do we also have a circular strip ROC in s domain just like we have in z domain as you told?

Comment: Yes. In s domain, we have a strip that is parallel to the y axis of the s plane.

Comment: "strip that is parallel to the y axis of the s plane" Will that strip be circular/ring shaped? or you mean that strip is imaginary(y axis) itself?

Comment: I couldn't understand  :"This can be generalised for all finite duration signals that their ROC consists of entire z plane (xy plane) except at z=0 or z=∞ or at both."                     If ROC consists of either z=0 or z=∞ ,but not both,will our signal be considered finite duration or infinite duration in that case??

Comment: For a right sided finite signal, ROC is the entire z plane except z=0 and for a left sided finite signal, ROC will be entire z plane except z=$\infty $. For a two sided finite signal, ROC will be the entire z plane except both z=0 and z=$\infty$ . The example I have given is a two sided case.

Comment: "This Z transform will not exist only if z=∞ (for the first term) and z=0 (for the last term)"              your this statement applies to all cases or only to your example x[n]={1,2,3} ??

Comment: It holds for all two sided finite sequences